# how to parse xml file having fluctuating tags and it's values, and how to parse it to android device.

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I want to parse this xml file which having fluctuating tags and it's values,
and i also want to parse it to android device. So i want to know what is the process to parse this xml code....?
And again i want to retrieve this to android device how it should be possible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<Snippest>
    <Quadrant_I>
        <YQ_1>
            <YQ1>G</YQ1>
            <YQ2>C</YQ2>
            <YQ5>I</YQ5>
        </YQ_1>
        <YQ_2>
            <YQ1>F</YQ1>
            <YQ2>I</YQ2>
        </YQ_2>
        <YQ_5>
            <YQ1>B</YQ1>
            <YQ2>G</YQ2>
            <YQ5>C</YQ5>
            <YQ6>I</YQ6>
        </YQ_5>
        <YQ_6>
            <YQ1>G</YQ1>
            <YQ2>C</YQ2>
            <YQ5>I</YQ5>
            <YQ6>F</YQ6>
            <YQ3>E</YQ3>
            <YQ4>J</YQ4>
        </YQ_6>
    </Quadrant_I>
    <Quadrant_II>
        <YQ_3>
            <YQ1>F</YQ1>
            <YQ2>E</YQ2>
        </YQ_3>
        <YQ_4>
            <YQ1>F</YQ1>
            <YQ2>E</YQ2>
        </YQ_4>
        <YQ_7>
            <YQ1>F</YQ1>
            <YQ2>E</YQ2>
        </YQ_7>
        <YQ_8>
            <YQ1>NULL</YQ1>
        </YQ_8>
    </Quadrant_II>
    <Quadrant_III>
        <YQ_10>
            <YQ1>B</YQ1>
            <YQ2>H</YQ2>
            <YQ5>G</YQ5>
            <YQ6>D</YQ6>
            <YQ3>E</YQ3>
            <YQ4>F</YQ4>
            <YQ7>I</YQ7>
            <YQ8>J</YQ8>
            <YQ9>A</YQ9>
            <YQ10>C</YQ10>
        </YQ_10>
        <YQ_13>
            <YQ1>NULL</YQ1>
        </YQ_13>
        <YQ_14>
            <YQ1>B</YQ1>
            <YQ2>H</YQ2>
            <YQ5>E</YQ5>
        </YQ_14>
        <YQ_9>
            <YQ1>B</YQ1>
            <YQ2>G</YQ2>
        </YQ_9>
    </Quadrant_III>
    <Quadrant_IV>
        <YQ_11>
            <YQ1>NULL</YQ1>
        </YQ_11>
        <YQ_12>
            <YQ1>NULL</YQ1>
        </YQ_12>
        <YQ_15>
            <YQ1>H</YQ1>
            <YQ2>E</YQ2>
        </YQ_15>
        <YQ_16>
            <YQ1>NULL</YQ1>
        </YQ_16>
    </Quadrant_IV>
</Snippest>
```

Comment: Is thsi XML format set in stone? Has it been force on you? Or, are you able to structure it in a more uniform fashion? `<Snippest><Quadrant id="I"><YQ id="1"><YQ1>...</YQ1><YQ2>...</YQ2>...</YQ>...</Quadrant>...`. Or even, just making the Quadrants follow a more uniform structure really as the YQ tags, while confusing as their names are so similar, are relatively uniform. If not then your options are to check our SAX (parse and read chunks), DOM (build whole model) and STAX (streamed for large files) as your first answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Below parsers are available for you.
you have to choose one depends on your application.

Dom,
Stax,
Sax

see here for [more details](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html) and I have compared these parsers in my [blog post](http://sanjayacl.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-choose-xml-parser.html)